# Squash grid view together to avoid strange appearance

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview, twitter-bootstrap-3

Example: http://www.codeply.com/go/2Mf71NEv42

I have some grid sections are have varying height which causes the strange view seen above. I want to nudge the last box up like:

---

[image: Nudging]

---

.. so that it looks like ..

---

[image: Nudged]

---

**Is this possible?**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but based on your code I believe you need to carefully place your "col-md-4"

In bootstrap, one row of 100% width is add up to 12 so if you plan to have 3 columns in a row, you would have 3 "col-md-4" where md >= 992px <1200px

So instead of placing col-md-4 to all the panels. You should consider placing the panels like below:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>##Panel1</div>
                <div>##Panel2</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>##Panel3</div>
                <div>##Panel4</div>
                <div>##Panel5</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>##Panel6</div>
                <div>##Panel7</div>
                <div>##Panel8</div>
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[Try it here](http://www.codeply.com/go/whHyo8QQJQ)